# python pandas: list of sublist: total items number

Tags: python, pandas

I've a list like this one:

```
categories_list = [
    ['a', array([ 12994, 1262824, 145854,  92469]),
     'b', array([273300]),
     'c', array([341395, 32857711])],
    ['a', array([ 356424311,  165573412, 2032850784]),
     'b', array([2848105, 228835]),
     'c', array([])],
    ['a', array([1431689, 30655043, 1739919]),
     'b', array([597, 251911, 246600]),
     'c', array([35590])]
]
```

where each array belongs to the letter before.
Example: `a -> array([ 12994, 1262824, 145854,  92469]), b -> array([273300]), 'a' -> array([1431689, 30655043, 1739919]) and so on...`

So, is it possible to retrieve the total items number for each letter?
Desiderata:

```
----------
a      10
b       6
c       3
```

All suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pd.DataFrame(
    [dict(zip(x[::2], [len(y) for y in x[1::2]])) for x in categories_list]
).sum()

a    10
b     6
c     3
dtype: int64
```

---

- I'm aiming at creating a list of dictionaries.  So I have to fill in the `......` with something that parses each sub-list with a dictionary

  ```
  [ ...... for x in catgories_list]
  ```
- If I use `dict` on a list or generator of `tuples`, it will magically turn that into a dictionary with keys as the first value in the tuple and values as the second value in the tuple.

  ```
  dict(...list of tuples...)
  ```
- `zip` will give me that generator of `tuples`

  ```
  zip(list one, list two)
  ```
- I know that in each sub-list, my keys are at the even indices `[0, 2, 4...]` and values are at the odd indices `[1, 3, 5, ...]`

  ```
  #   even    odd
  zip(x[::2], x[1::2])
  ```
- but `x[1::2]` will be arrays, and I don't want the arrays.  I want the length of the arrays.

  ```
  #   even                     odd
  zip(x[::2], [len(y) for y in x[1::2]])
  ```
- `pandas.DataFrame` will take a list of dictionaries and create a dataframe.
- Finally, use `sum` to count the lengths.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation, piRSquared

Answer (score 0):

I use `groupby` in order to group key in column `0, 2, 4` (which has keys `a`, `b`, `c` respectively) and then count number of distinct item number in the next column. Number in the group in this case is `len(set(group))` (or `len(group)` if you want just total length of the group). See the code below:

```
from itertools import groupby, chain

count_distincts = []
cols = [0, 2, 4]
for c in cols:
    for gid, group in groupby(categories_list, key=lambda x: x[c]):
        group = list(chain(*[list(g[c + 1]) for g in group]))
        count_distincts.append([gid, len(set(group))])
```

**Output** `[['a', 10], ['b', 6], ['c', 3]]`